# Tomcat 6 cant access applications

Tags: tomcat

I downloaded tomcat 6, changed the port on server.xml to 8040 and started tomcat. I don't see anything by going to localhost:8040, localhost:8040/manager/html and other apps. I have jdk 1.7 installed and tomcat 7 installed previously as a service. But then removed tomcat 7 and I am using the zipped version of tomcat 6. The installer version of tomcat 7 worked fine.

When tomcat starts, I see the following

```
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], r
    andom [true].
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:14 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8040
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:14 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 2551 ms
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:16 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8040
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:16 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
    Feb 17, 2012 10:16:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 1507 ms
```

Output from netstat

```
    C:\Windows\System32>netstat

    Active Connections

      Proto  Local Address
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:12080
      TCP    127.0.0.1:49167
      TCP    127.0.0.1:49168
      TCP    127.0.0.1:62994
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63002
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63008
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63023
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63029
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63039
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63041
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63044
      TCP    192.168.1.5:60959
      TCP    192.168.1.5:60982
      TCP    192.168.1.5:62995
      TCP    192.168.1.5:62996
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63035
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63036
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63038
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63040
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63043
      TCP    192.168.1.5:63045
      TCP    [::1]:1521
      TCP    [::1]:49177
```

With netstat -a -n looks liek this

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file snippet shown above does not reveal any errors. Do you receive any error while trying to access the applications on port 8040 ? Have you tried executing netstat and performing a grep on port 8040 ?

Comment: I have added output from netstat, i do not see a 8040

Comment: Try netstat -a -n ; also are there any errors in the log files ?

Comment: Added output from netstat -a -n. it shows up but the ip address is 0.0.0.0. The logs have the same information as the command prompt in catalina.out

Comment: The netstat looks okay ; try accessing the app using the hostname:8040/app_name